# Operator Overloading with Constant Iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a constant iterator class which contains the following methods for overloading several operator functions

```
self_reference operator=( const SDAL_Const_Iter& src ) {
    index = src.index;
    return *this;
}

self_reference operator++() {
    index = index + 1;
    return *this;
}

self_type operator++(int) {
    SDAL_Const_Iter results = *this;
    ++index;
    return results;
}
```

The `index` variable is of type `const int`.

My compiler is complaining that I am attempting to modify a constant object (More specifically, "Error C2166: l-value specifies constant object"), which I am aware of; however, I see no other way of overloading these functions. Can someone please elaborate on how to go about writing these overloads without causing compiler issues?

Comment: Why did you make `index` `const`?

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the code in `++*index` - int does not have an unary *. Why is the index a const int? A constant iterator should not allow non-const access to the container's data. The iterator itself, though, is changeable (it has to be able to iterate).

Comment: I can see the error now, I copied this code from an iterator I had written before that iterated over a linked list rather than an array. I changed the type of index to `int` and it resolved the error

Comment: @Kevin Good! :) I'll make the comment above into an answer, then. If it solved your issue, can you accept it, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in `const int` as `index` variable.

A constant iterator should not allow non-const access to the container's data. The iterator itself, though, is changeable (it has to be able to iterate). Changing `index` to `int` should fix the problem.